# Sitecore WebForms for Marketers : send email to users

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using Send Email Message action. I have added one action for send email to admin and another thank you mail to user who filled the form so my question is how I can add user email in Send Email Editor. I tried to add email Insert Field but it is not working.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of wffm are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.0 version

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Form Designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

By Default, the `TO` Dropdown only allows content from the `Email` Field Type.  To allow other field types, please go to to the `Send Email Message` action found here by default: `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message`

go to the `Editor` section, and enter the following into the `QueryString` field:

`AllowedToTypes={84ABDA34-F9B1-4D3A-A69B-E28F39697069}|{YOUR CUSTOM FIELD TYPE GUID}`

The first guid is for the standard `Email` Field type, and the second one will be your custom field.  This should allow you to choose from those fields  in the `TO` field.

For best practices, you should duplicate the `Send Email Message` action, and apply the changes there to prevent issues with future upgrades.

To allow your custom fields to be selectable for the `CC` and `From` fields as well, your query string would look like this:

`AllowedToTypes={84ABDA34-F9B1-4D3A-A69B-E28F39697069}|{YOUR CUSTOM FIELD TYPE GUID}&AllowedCCTypes={84ABDA34-F9B1-4D3A-A69B-E28F39697069}|{YOUR CUSTOM FIELD TYPE GUID}&AllowedFromTypes={84ABDA34-F9B1-4D3A-A69B-E28F39697069}|{YOUR CUSTOM FIELD TYPE GUID}`

From there, to send an email to one of the fields on the form, simply choose the field by clicking the little arrow next to the 'To' field

[image: field selector]

I have noticed a bug in previous version of wffm where it places double brackets around the field name, for example: [[email address]]. If you notice the double brackets [[..]], then erase the entire field and select it again as shown above.

Comment: My side arrow button is not visible.I have also tried to add email like this [[email address]] but it is also not working. It is giving error: We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you change the field type to just "Email" instead of "email with placeholder", do you get the arrow next to the to field in the email editor?

Comment: When you get the  "We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request" message, there should be an error message to go along with this. Check your logs for the message.

Comment: Also, are you getting the admin email? Are your SMTP settings correct?

Comment: I have changed "Email with Placeholder" to "Email" but still it is not showing arrow. Admin email is working fine. If in the user email i applied some static email it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found there is an issue a with the To: field in certain browsers - not sure if this is related to Bug 402562.

In Chrome I get js error messages but in Firefox I can insert the email field with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

As stated my @amir818, you need to add the field name with brackets in the To field. If you are using Chrome then the arrow may not work due to a javascript error, it works in IE though.

Alternate way to add the field into the message body from the `Insert Field` droplist and then copy+paste into the `TO` field. Looking at your field names it should be `[Emailaddress]`.

The double brackets that amir mentioned is a bug, you can get a fix from Sitecore and quote ticket number 402562. When you edit the form again, the field has 2 sets of brackets added which then breaks the send action, e.g. it would end up as `[[Emailaddress]]` which is incorrect and therefore fails

Comment: I have added field name [Emailaddress] but when i reopen it display me like this [[Hidden]] and I also checked in all browser - Chrome, Mozilla and IE but in all three browser arrow is not displaying.

Comment: If it's changing from [Emailaddress] to [Hidden] then there is a different issue. It looks like you are using custom fields, try with default Sitecore WFFM fields, it may be an issue with your code.

Comment: I have changed "Email with Placeholder" custom field to WFFM "Email" field now it is not converting into [Hidden] but also not working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you check the logs again. Can you confirm the field is still named `Emailaddress`

Comment: Also, make sure you have published the changes :)

Comment: Yes you were right it was problem of custom field which i have created because of that arrow is not showing. I just created new form than compare after that i found problem. Can you please help me what is problem in this code.

Comment: Here is my code 
> public class SingleLineText : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SingleLineText
    {
        [VisualCategory("Appearance")]
        [VisualFieldType(typeof(TextAreaField)), Localize]
        [VisualProperty("PlaceholderText:", 100)]
        public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }
        protected override void DoRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            this.textbox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", this.PlaceholderText);

            base.DoRender(writer);
        }
    }